# Django - Proper exception for ContentType.get_object_for_this_type()

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes

I am learning to use the [ContentType framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#methods-on-contenttype-instances) and need some help raising an exception for `get_object_for_this_type()`.

[According to the code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/contenttypes/models/#ContentType.get_object_for_this_type):

> Returns an object of this type for the keyword arguments given.
>           Basically, this is a proxy around this object_type's get_object() model
>           method. The ObjectNotExist exception, if thrown, will not be caught,
>           so code that calls this method should catch it.

I am wondering if there is a way to do this without bringing in the actual models being referenced. For example if I wanted to do something like this:

```
for model in models
    try:
        i = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="Users", model=model)
        obj = i.get_object_for_this_type(user=self)
        self.profile_type = obj
        self.save()
    except ContentType.object.DoesNotExist:
        continue
```

This exception informs me that `'ContentTypeManager' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'`. Is there a way to do this without specifying all of the models in models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on some other part of the docs, don't ask me where. The proper exception to be used in this situation is `django.core.excpetions.ObjectDoesnotExist`

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

for model in models:
    try:
        i = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="Users", model=model)
        obj = i.get_object_for_this_type(user=self)
        self.slug = obj.slug
        self.save()
        return self.profile_type
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        continue
```