# Check if an object exists in django content type framework

Tags: django, django-contenttypes

I want to be able to check if the object exists using get_object_for_this_type

```
content_type = get_object_or_404(ContentType, pk = id1)
 if content_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk= id2).exists():`
```

This is obviously not working because it's not a query. Is there a way around it without calling the actual mode.

I'm trying to avoid try and except as proposed in the following answer:
[Django - Proper exception for ContentType.get_object_for_this_type()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988910/django-proper-exception-for-contenttype-get-object-for-this-type)

Comment: The linked answer is wrong - it should just use `ContentType.DoesNotExist` - but why don't you want to use try/except? That is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using try and except. But to answer your question, I generally prefer to avoid using exceptions to perform flow control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a 404 when the content object doesn't exist, you can pass `content_type.model_class()` to `get_object_or_404()`, like so:

```py
content_type = get_object_or_404(ContentType, pk=id1)
content_object = get_object_or_404(content_type.model_class(), pk=id2)
```